# Issue while editing a Table using SWT TableEditor

Tags: swt

http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet88.java

In the Table Editor example described in the above link, EDITABLECOLUMN is set to "1", i.e. edit second column of the table.

If i want to edit the first column i changed that variable to "0", and when i try to edit that column(1st) in the table, the second column value disappears. I mean the Text widget which is being created so as to serve as a listener for the cell, it occupying the next column as well.

[image: after selecting/editing the table column 0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you perhaps have following line in your code?

> editor.minimumWidth = 250;